# run yeoman from within yeoman - is it possible?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm writing a generator that should conditionally run another generator as a hook. Is it supported by yeoman nicely? Or am I only able to spawn OS processes that will run yeoman eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeoman does support composability: http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html

```
this.composeWith('some-name', {
  args: ['bar'],
  options: {testFramework: 'mocha'}
}, {
  // that's the path to your npm local version
  local: require.resolve('generator-some-name')
});
```

Comment: That's it! Unfortunately, yeoman docs you linked are missing an example of composing a local subgenerator  with `generator.composeWith()`.